# Remote login: Putty Works, HeidiSQL doesn't

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to login to my server with HeidiSQL.  I prefer it to the console sometimes because of the GUI and quick import commands.

This occurs on the same computer -

**Using Putty:**

[Server Host] port 22
SSH private key

The console connects with private key, I input the [username], and I'm in, no need for password.  It will not login without using the SSH key.

**Using HeidiSQL:**
[Server Host] port 3306 
[username] 
[password left empty] 
[SSL blank - put Putty private key .ppk ]

It hangs, and then gives me error 10060.  Does not matter if I put the password in or not.  If I change the port to 22 it errors immediately with "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0".

I'm not sure if I'm filling out HeidiSQL correctly, but another database I did this exact same formula and it worked.

Comment: Are you sure the SQL server is configured to allow login using a key? And are you sure the client you are using can use the same key for both SSH and SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that HeidiSQL is attempting to connect to port 3306 on the public IP address of the server.  Most distros these days have MySQL configured to only listen locally.

You could verify this by running a the following command on the remote server:

```
netstat -tapn | egrep "^tcp.*:3306\s+0.0.0.0.*LISTEN.*$"
```

If you get something back like:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

It means that MySQL is configured to only listen locally.

To get around this without having to reconfigure MySQL, you could set up a port-forward via PuTTY first, then point HeidiSQL to a port on your local system.  To do so, perform the following steps:

- Open PuTTY
- Create a new session
- Navigate the tree on the left to: Connection -> SSH -> Tunnels
- On the right, type '3306' into the 'Source port:' box.
- Type '127.0.0.1:3306' into the 'Destination:' box.
- Click the 'Add' button.
- The 'Forwarded ports:' box should now contain: 'L3306 127.0.0.1:3306'
- Be sure to fill-in any other information for this session, such as the host's IP or FQDN in the proper places, and be sure to include any SSH keys if necessary.
- Save the session. (You'll need to go back to the 'Session' branch in the tree.)
- Now 'Open' (i.e. connect) the session.

Once the session is connected, you can point HeidiSQL to 127.0.0.1:3306 and you should have access to the remote MySQL server.  The bonus to this being that the connection will be encrypted over the internet.

Comment: I followed the steps but `127.0.0.1:3306` connects me to my local mysql server. The session is active in putty!